# ggplot2 Plotting scatterplot with 2 variables and labelling x-axis based on another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
df<-data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
         group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
         level = c(0.1,0.5,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.5,0.9,0.3))
```

I would like to use ggplot2 to plot a scatter plot, where every point (x,y) corresponds to the values  of `(ID,level)`. But I want to label the x-axis based on the `group` value, so that the x-axis in this case would have 3 ticks: under tick "1", there would be 5 points, tick "2" with 3 points and tick "3" with 2 points.

Comment: Could you please add the current and expected output and what has already failed?

Comment: From your description e.g "under tick "1", there would be 5 points" it sounds that your result could be achieved by simply mapping `group` directly on `x`. Maybe you could clarify how your plot should look like.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was I want the plot to look like three different scatterplots (stitched together), one based on each `group` value and the points based on `(ID, level)` values, so for example under tick "1", the points that are plotted should be: (1, 0.1), (2, 0.5), (3, 0.2), (4, 0.3), (5, 0.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar idea as by Allan but with some additional tweaking to show the group labels as tick labels:

```r
library(ggplot2)

breaks <- tapply(df$ID, df$group, median)
ggplot(df, aes(ID, level)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = NULL) +
  facet_grid(~group, scales = "free_x", switch = "x" , space = "free_x") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for facets?

```r
ggplot(df, aes(ID, level)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(.~group, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10, expand = expansion(0, 0.5)) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm"),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "#A0B6FF", color = "black"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "grey", fill = NA),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 20))
```

[image]

Comment: This time your faster than. Spend to much time on tweaking the plot. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The tidyverse way:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% ggplot(aes(x = group, y = level)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(ID)), size = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1:3))
```

[image]